# How to include html tags in a js response in ajax call in Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a controller method for login my app like this:

```
def create
  user = User.find_by(mail: params[:session][:mail].downcase)
  if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
    if user.confirmed? 
        # Stuff when login is OK
        .......         
    else
        logout
        text = I18n.t("error.login.confirmation", :link => ActionController::Base.helpers.link_to(I18n.t("button"), confirm_user_path(user), :class => 'btn btn-info'))
        @result = ActionController::Base.helpers.sanitize(text, :tags => ['br','a']).html_safe
        respond_to do |format|
            format.html { render 'new' }
            format.js { @result.html_safe }

        end
    end
  # more stuff
  .......
  end  
end
```

If the user has not confirmed the email, I want to show him a message with a link to re-send the confirmation mail:

```
 Please confirm your signup. <br /> <br /> <a class="btn btn-info" href="/users/48/confirm_user">Re-send confirmation mail.</a>
```

UPDATE: This is how render the view

```
$("p.bg-danger").html("<%= @result %>")
```

Comment: I'd escape them with html entities, such as &gt; and &nbsp; then parse those client side and add to dom with js or jquery.

Comment: @Todd: I have updated the question with the render view. How do you do that parsing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `create` action, it is not needed to type `@result.html_safe`, because it's actually does nothing here. Instead, you would like probably to tell your controller not to render layout.

```
def create
  # ...
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { render 'new' }
    format.js { render layout: false }

  end
end
```

Then, within **create.js.erb**:

```
$("p.bg-danger").html('<%=j @result %>');
```

Comment: It works! But I don´t why. How @result reachs the view? By the '@' in the controller?

Comment: Yep, `@` means that given variable becomes instance variable. Instance variables are available in any instance controller methods. So that, any instance variable defined in controller is also available within view, because it just a template (`ERB` in this case) rendered by appropriate controller method.